# How does a pilot switch from IFR to VFR mid-flight?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

I had a pilot tell me that a rude ATC controller was making him fly way off route and through clouds and turbulence. So he switched to VFR and climbed out of the mess and towards the direction he wanted to go. Without getting into who was right or wrong in this particular situation, how does one cancel IFR mid-flight?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate since it sounds like the pilot just canceled IFR and went on their merry way. VFR-on-top is still an IFR clearance and you must remain on the cleared route unless deviation is authorized.

Answer (score 7):

You simply tell ATC your request:

> A: DEXPL, request cancel IFR.
>   R: DEXPL, roger, report VMC.
>   A: DEXPL, we are VMC.
>   R: DEXPL, IFR cancelled at 20. Squawk VFR, approved to leave frequency.

Comment: Yes, it really is this simple. The operative words are "Cancel IFR". You can even ask to maintain the current squawk code for VFR flight following (in the US, at least).

Comment: what is the *"cancelled at 20"* part?  Is that a Zulu time? An Altitude?

Comment: @abelenky Minutes after the full hour.

Comment: What if you are not yet vmc? Will atc vector you to a vmc area before canceling?

Comment: @TomMcW How would ATC know where VMC is? :) Pilot needs to indicate where he will be VMC and he will be vectored there.

Comment: So you request, for example, an altitude change that will get you out of the clouds then ask to cancel? I presume you let them know that you are wanting to get out of imc so they know why you're asking?

Comment: The US also have the concept of VFR-on-top, which is still IFR. I am not familiar with that though... so yes, I would essentially tell ATC I want a climb or descent to get into VMC with the intention to cancel IFR.

Comment: Just a couple points to make:  1.)  Cancelling IFR is not a request, you are telling them you no longer required their services.  2.)  In most cases you are doing the controller a favor by reducing their workload.

Comment: @MichaelHall In ICAO/EASA ops it's a request, because ATC can deny it temporarily. I believe in FAA-land, you can simply cancel without approval.